# How can I get the tooltip text from a website using selenium and python where the text comes from a javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I am trying to get the tooltip text that shows when I hover over how long ago the game was played
https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/summoner/eune/AnFrey99
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/921im.png)

In the html code it doesn't shows the text and I figure it comes from a javascript and each rows has a script inside the tr tag, but so far I was not able to get the value of the var newTooltipData .

```
    var newTooltipData = {"match-2733966814": (new Date(1612964002882).toLocaleDateString() + " " + new Date(1612964002882).toLocaleTimeString()) + " - 31min 48s"};
    if (window.tooltipData) {
        window.tooltipData = Object.assign(window.tooltipData, newTooltipData);
    } else {
        window.tooltipData = newTooltipData;
    }
```

I want to get the exact date for each row along with other information that I already done.
Here is my code and my tries.

```
driver_second = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver_second.get("https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/summoner/eune/"+'AnFrey99')
time.sleep(5)
accept_button=driver_second.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/button[2]")
accept_button.click()
tabel=driver_second.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='data_table relative recentGamesTable']")
rows=tabel.find_elements_by_xpath("tbody/tr")
for row in rows:
    elements=row.find_elements_by_xpath("td")
    if(len(elements)>1):
            script=row.find_element_by_xpath("script")
            data=elements[2].find_element_by_xpath("a/div[3]")
            data=script.get_property('innerHTML')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hover the div, JavaScript will append a new div to the website with the ID `'tooltip'` (full source of the function [here](https://lolg-cdn.porofessor.gg/app.js?v=1612819629)):

```
var TooltipManager = (function () {
    [...]
            var tooltipElement = $('#tooltip');
            if (!tooltipElement.length) {
                $('body').append('<div id="tooltip"></div>'); #New Div appended
                [...]
```

Therefore Selenium can find this new div id = "tooltip" after you hover over the div, which calls this function.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains    
import time
    
driver_second = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver_second.get('https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/summoner/eune/AnFrey99')
time.sleep(3)

infos = driver_second.find_elements_by_class_name('gameDate')

for i in infos:
    hover = ActionChains(driver_second).move_to_element(i)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    DateofGame = driver_second.find_element_by_id('tooltip').text
    print(DateofGame)
```

output:

```
10.2.2021 14:33:22 - 31min 48s
10.2.2021 14:02:55 - 20min 47s
29.1.2021 04:12:09 - 29min 13s
29.1.2021 03:23:24 - 34min 54s
29.1.2021 02:44:22 - 32min 46s
29.1.2021 01:35:22 - 32min 48s
28.1.2021 23:23:19 - 24min 35s
10.1.2021 01:12:34 - 21min 8s
8.1.2021 22:27:35 - 21min 4s
8.1.2021 22:08:01 - 14min 51s
```